# Validating a simple .NET collection is failing when it should pass

Tags: c#, .net, validation, fluentvalidation

I'm trying to create a FluentValidation rule that tests that my `IList<string>` has to contain 1 or more items.

Therefore:

- It cannot be null
- It cannot be empty
- Count > 0

Using FluentValidation, I've setup a rule and then a unit test. The unit test fails. 
I thought that `.NotEmpty()` will check to see those 3 checks (above)?

Can someone please explain which assumption I made (with respect to F.V.) I have wrong?

#### Show me da codez

```
public class AgentValidator : AbstractValidator<Agent>
{
    public AgentValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(agent => agent.Name).NotEmpty()
            .WithMessage("A name is required. eg. Jane Smith.");

        RuleFor(agent => agent.AgencyIds).NotEmpty()
            .WithMessage("At least one AgencyId is requires where this Agent works at.");
    }
}
```

and the test.

```
[Fact]
public void GivenNoAgencyIds_Validate_ShouldHaveAnError()
{
    // Arrange.
    var agencyIds = new string[]{}; // No Agency Id's.

    // Act & Assert.
    _agentValidator.ShouldNotHaveValidationErrorFor(agent => agent.AgencyIds, agencyIds);
}
```

And finally, the error message

> FluentValidation.TestHelper.ValidationTestExceptionExpected no
>   validation errors for property AgencyIds    at
>   FluentValidation.TestHelper.ValidatorTester`2.ValidateNoError(T instanceToValidate)
>   in
>   c:\Projects\FluentValidation\src\FluentValidation\TestHelper\ValidatorTester.cs:
>   line 40

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're using the wrong testing method:

```
_agentValidator.ShouldNotHaveValidationErrorFor(...)
```

`ShouldNotHaveValidationErrorFor` ensures that an error *does not exist*. But you WANT an error to exist!  The function you want would be [`ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor`](https://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Testing).

Comment: Confirmed. FML. Late night Midnight programming does this to you :(